# Insert plain HTML into template

Tags: angularjs

I use AngularJs 1.4 and I need to insert plain HTML which I receive from $http.get() into my template as HTML tags like jQuery inserts plain HTML into DOM as tags.

Conroller code:

```
var onLoadUrl = function( data ){

    $scope.joomlaComponent = data;

}

joomlaComponent.loadUrl( $location.absUrl(), true ).then( onLoadUrl );
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="joomla-component.tpl">
    <div class="uk-grid uk-margin-large">
        {{joomlaComponent}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Now it insert it as plain text but I need to have it like HTML tags inserted into a document's DOM.

Comment: there is ng-bind-html directive, to be use with ngSanitize module.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But it removes all my js scripts from the html.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to call `$scope.$evalAsync()` in your `onLoadUrl` function to trigger a digest cycle. Then, use `ng-bind-html="joomlaComponent"` instead of `{{ joomlaComponent }}`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But it removes all my js scripts from the html.

Comment: Right, you need to read about `$sce` and sanitization. For now, in your controller, use `$scope.joomlaComponent = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my life! ))